# C++ do-while infinite loop

Tags: c++

I don't know why my do-while loop is infinite.

```
int number_1, number_2 = 0;
do {
    cin.sync();
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Give number_1: ";
    cin >> number_1;
    while (cin.good() == 1) {
        number_2 += number_1;
        cout << "Give new number_1: ";
        cin >> number_1;
    };
} while (number_2<1000);
```

Untill i write correct number_1 everything is fine, but if i write incorrect value (for example "a") my loop becomes infinite because line 6 is ignored. Where is the clue?

Comment: Are you trying to loop through inputs until their sums are over 1000?

Comment: maybe you should store the input in a string and check for validity?

Comment: Yes Hill, thats what i am doing. But my main problem is why line 6 is ignored and i cant put new number_1.

Comment: If you don't type in a number then the input will have an error and stop working until you clear the error and flush the input

Comment: An if you do type in a number it will keep looping asking you for anoher one because there is no way out of that loop (unless you make an error)

Comment: And how can i fix it? For this reason i have put cin.sync() and cin.clear();

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532530/infinite-loop-without-accepting-input or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622338/infinite-loop-when-reading-in-input-file or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521320/why-do-i-get-an-infinite-loop-if-i-enter-a-letter-rather-than-a-number

Comment: `cin.sync()` does not remove characters from input queue. In fact it does not do anything you should be concerned with unless you know exactly what it does on specific OS/compiler/library/stream type.